# PhoneGap Plugin Chromecast iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova

i'am searching a phonegap plugin for chromecast (http://www.google.de/chrome/devices/chromecast/) that support iOS. but i find only android plugins, like this:
http://plugreg.com/search?q=chromecast

it is possible to create? or is it does not work?

thanks!

Comment: Hi have you got the answer..